# Sharepoint list If formula

Tags: calculated-column

I have a column that needs to return the value of another column based on if the value in a third column = S

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to use IF statements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx

For example:

```
=IF([Column1]<=[Column2], "OK", "Not OK")
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is this:

Comment: if column 4 = "S" then column 6 value if not then "0"

Comment: In excel I would write it:

Comment: =IF(A4="S",A6,"0")

Comment: It works the same way Excel formulas do.  For example: =IF([Column1]="S", [Column2], "").

Answer (score 1):

In addition to John's answer which seems best,

You can attach a Item Adding event to your list or you may able to use [calculated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175023/how-calculated-column-works-in-sharepoint).

Here's the code to give you an idea,

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        string newFieldValue = GetNewFieldValue();
        object oldFieldValue = properties.AfterProperties[COLUMN_NAME];
        if (oldFieldValue == null || oldFieldValue.ToString() != newFieldValue)
        {
            properties.AfterProperties[COLUMN_NAME] = newFieldValue;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Log the error, or take another appropriate action.
    }
    finally
    {
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
    }
}
```